# SQL query order by pattern

Tags: mysql, sql, database, case, sql-order-by

I am using this particular example

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp

I want to get the list of customers ordered by country pattern.

For instance, `Country` starting with `As` should be first in number, followed by countries starting with `Ge`, followed by country starting with `Fr`.

If I need to order by using 1 pattern search in the country I can achieve using the following code :

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN Country LIKE 'Fr%' THEN 0
ELSE 1
END)ASC;
```

How can I add 2 more conditions to the `ORDER BY` clause ? Thank you.

Comment: Just add other cases to your `CASE ... WHEN` ?

Answer (score 5):

You can add multiple `CASE` for your additional *"conditions"* by incrementing the number each time:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Customers
ORDER BY (CASE
    WHEN Country LIKE 'As%' THEN 0
    WHEN Country LIKE 'Ge%' THEN 1
    WHEN Country LIKE 'Fr%' THEN 2
    ELSE 3
END) ASC;
```

Comment: tried this and I am receiving the following error ```rror 1: could not prepare statement (1 near "CASE": syntax error)```

Comment: @Tanu I added the `CASE` keyword too many times, sorry. I fixed it.

Comment: I think he could also use that case inside the select and name it casecountry and then order by casecountry desc. But both ways work :D